# Text recommendation - suggestion

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

I am working on a personal project. I worked on some publicly available data sets. I have to build a text recommendation system that suggest users meaning full text(1 -2 lines) based on pre-defined rules.

How do I go about building a text recommendation system and how do I define the rules (The rules are simple checks like AC, then suggest a text if not suggest alternate text). I also need to know how I can make the system learn by itself to update rules

ANy inputs, links to research papers, github links etc will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will be encountering a cold start [problem](https://www.yuspify.com/blog/cold-start-problem-recommender-systems/).

The simple solution would be to recommend all-time favorites text. More sophisticated solutions are [here](https://kojinoshiba.com/recsys-cold-start/).

Thereafter you can use collaborative filtering by collecting implicit data like views, clicks, comment , bookmarks of the text. Because users seldom give ratings.
So you can use implicit data as:
'VIEW': 1.0,
   'LIKE': 2.0, 
   'BOOKMARK': 3.0, 
   'FOLLOW': 4.0,
   'COMMENT CREATED': 5.0, as ratings.

This kind of reccomender system can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-collaborative-filtering-recommender-system-with-clickstream-data-dffc86c8c65)